# After storing data in heap, how can I store it in struct without stack overflow?

Tags: c, memory, struct, heap-memory

I am reading the entire contents of a file into a character array successfully.  I then want to store that data in a struct.

I'm certain that initializing the array in the struct to a million is incorrect, but the file is large, and it requires anywhere from 500k to 1m bytes.

```
struct ArrayStoredInHeap
{
    char entireFile[1000000];   
};
```

Saving the file into the char array below works, if I use a smaller file, and change the above struct char array to a much smaller container size.

```
char *GetFileContent(char *filePath)
{
    char *buffer = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;

    FILE *file = fopen(filePath, "r");

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(file);

    rewind(file);

    buffer = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(*buffer));

    fread(buffer, size, 1, file);

    buffer[size] = '\0';

    return buffer;

}
```

The problem, other than the obviously wrong struct array initialization is that whenever I use a larger file, I get a stack overflow exception when initializing `myStruct`

```
int main (void)
{
    char *file = {"file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"};
    int numberOfFiles = strlen(file);

    struct ArrayStoredInHeap myStruct[numberOfFiles];

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++)
    {
        struct ArrayStoredInHeap tmpStruct;

        strcpy(tmpStruct.entireFile, GetFileContent(&file[i]));

        myStruct[i] = tmpStruct;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n", myStruct[i].entireFile);        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that will let the stack overflow... Why not use heap memory?

Comment: `numberOfFiles = strlen(file);` is not what you want. Lookup what `strlen` does.

Comment: The buffer returned by `GetFileContent` is never freed. You'll run out of heap!

Comment: `strcpy(tmpStruct.entireFile, GetFileContent(&file[i]));` may overflow your tmpStruct: the first is a fixed length; the second is a dynamic length, and that could be larger.

Comment: What does your compiler tell you? Do you have warnings turned on???

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I am using the heap, using malloc.  ```strlen``` is what I thought I needed since ```sizeof``` would return the size of the pointer.  I'll try to fix that first, but I don't think it solves the problem.

Comment: my compiler tells me 'Stack overflow' (it's not a great compiler).  Man, what is up with these super quick downvotes.  I guess I didn't phrase the question correctly.

Comment: It us niot your compiler that says "stack overflow". It is the run-time environment. You donlt seem to understand that stack space is limited. That is why there is a heap.

Comment: Did you see that I was using the heap?  I understand that stack place is limited, that's why I used heap space instead.

Comment: I'll edit the question later, so it's more clear what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you **must** to use automatic storage variables - increase the stack size.

for example this way:

```
int SeStack(rlim_t size)
{
    struct rlimit rlim;
    if(!getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rlim))
    {
        if (rlim.rlim_cur <= size)
        {
            rlim.rlim_cur = size;
            return setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rlum);
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return EPERM;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still store the data in a struct whilst also storing them in the heap

lets look at the following struct

```
struct ArrayStoredInHeap{
    char * entireFile;
}
```

then you can do something as follows

```
int main(){
    char * fileName;
    // get file contents
    char * fileContent = GetFileContent(&fileName);
    struct ArrayStoredInHeap fileStruct;
    // allocate memory 
    fileStruct.entireFile = (char*)malloc(strlen(fileContent)+1); //Not sure if +1 is necessary
    // copy file contents to struct
    strcpy(fileStruct.entireFile, fileContent);
    free(fileContent)
    /* another solution could be assigning the pointer right into the struct as follows:

    fileStruct.entireFile = GetFileContent(&fileName);
    */
}
```

Comment: He can just do `fileStruct.entireFile= GetFileContent(filename);`

Comment: it is not the answer of the OPs quesion

Comment: He hasn't really asked one.

Comment: One answer to that would be: store it in the heap!

Comment: That's correct, my question was how, when I was storing it in the heap already, but I didn't know how to allocate the memory in the struct.  I think using a pointer in your method will work.  Working on understanding it now.